# How to populate a HashMap with data from a txt file

Tags: java, hashmap, readfile, localdate, datetimeformatter

I need to put the following dates from Dates.txt file into a HashMap.

```
1 05.05.2017
2 11.12.2018
3 05.30.2020
4 03.15.2011
5 12.15.2000
6 10.30.2010
7 01.01.2004
8 12.31.1900
9 02.28.2014
10 10.10.2012
```

The format for the HashMap should be

Initial Hashmap:

```
2017-05-05:1
2018-11-12:2
2020-05-30:3
2011-03-15:4
2000-12-15:5
2010-10-30:6
2004-01-01:7
1900-12-31:8
2014-02-28:9
2012-10-10:10
```

My code snippet so far

```
public class driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        HashMap <LocalDate, Integer> dates = new HashMap <LocalDate, Integer>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("Dates.txt")); 
        while(s.hasNext())
        {
           dates.put(LocalDate.parse("mm.dd.yyyy"), Integer);
        }   

        System.out.println(dates);
    }
}
```

I am having trouble figuring out what to put in my dates.put(key,value) line of code so the HashMap is formatted as above. I'm not sure if it'd be better to read the txt file into an ArrayList then using put() to populate the HashMap. Any guidance or answers would be appreciated!

Comment: Does each line really start with an ascending integer (1 on the first, 2 on the second, etc), or are those just the row numbers?

Comment: Those are row numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the given data, it looks like there's no really reason to use a map - as you noted, you've struggled to find an appropriate value. You could accumulate them in to an `ArrayList`, or even a `HashSet` if the order isn't important instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
Map<LocalDate, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("Dates.txt"));
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    // Read a line
    String line = s.nextLine();
    // Split the line on whitespace
    String[] data = line.split("\\s+");
    if (data.length == 2) {
        map.put(LocalDate.parse(data[1], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM.dd.uuuu")), Integer.valueOf(data[0]));
    }
}
System.out.println(map);
```

**An example of parsing the date string in the given pattern:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("05.05.2017", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM.dd.uuuu"));
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2017-05-05
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: This looks great and makes sense, but when running the code snippet that creates the HashMap and reads in the txt file I get a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 error.

Comment: @acc13241 - I've updated the answer with a check, `if (data.length == 2)` which will prevent executing the line `map.put` if a line does not have two strings separated by whitespace. Feel free to comment in case of any further issue/doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative to the excellent answer already provided, this could be done by using streams:

```
Map<LocalDate, Integer> result = Files.lines(Paths.get("Dates.txt")
    .map(l -> l.split(" ")).filter(fs -> fs.length == 2)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
         fs -> LocalDate.parse(fs[1], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM.dd.uuuu")), 
         fs -> Integer.valueOf(fs[0]));
```